# Reading data on Serial port fails

Tags: c++, linux

I am currently working on a linux embedded board (sbc6000x if you are curious) and i am trying to create a mean of communication using the serial port.
I don't seems to have problems opening the port and writing in it but reading seems to be a problem. When reading, i have a little printf in a loop and i don't see it anywhere (and in the terminal chen using ctrl+C i can't forcequit the application so i think there is a problem somewhere).

My sending PC code look like this :

```
int open_port()
{
speed_t baud = B115200; /* baud rate */
int n, fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
std::cout << "Ouverture du port" << std::endl;
  fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR);
std::cout << "Configuration du port" << std::endl;

struct termios settings;
tcgetattr(fd, &settings);

cfsetospeed(&settings, baud); /* baud rate */
settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; /* no parity */
settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; /* 1 stop bit */
settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
settings.c_cflag |= CS8 | CLOCAL; /* 8 bits */
settings.c_lflag = ICANON; /* canonical mode */
settings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; /* raw output */

tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &settings); /* apply the settings */
tcflush(fd, TCOFLUSH);

  if (fd == -1)
  {
   /* Could not open the port. */
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");
    std::cout << "Echec de l'ouverture du port" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
std::cout << "Ecriture sur le port" << std::endl;
  n = write(fd, "TEST\r\n", 4);
  if (n < 0){

    std::cout << "Echec de l'écriture sur le port" << std::endl; //failed to write
  }
  else
  {
      std::cout << "Ecriture terminée" << std::endl;
  }
  }

  close(fd);  /* cleanup */
  return (fd);

}
```

When running it, on my ubuntu pc i have no error.

The target is like that :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

int res;
char buffer[20];
int tampon=0;
std::string data="";
res = system("printf \"Ecoute serial \n \" > /dev/tty1"); //sometext

speed_t baud = B115200; /* baud rate */
int n, fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
//std::cout << "Ouverture du port" << std::endl;
res = system("printf \"Ouverture du port \n \" > /dev/tty1"); //opening the port
fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR);
//std::cout << "Configuration du port" << std::endl;
res = system("printf \"Configuration du port \n \" > /dev/tty1"); //configuration of the port

struct termios settings;
tcgetattr(fd, &settings);

cfsetospeed(&settings, baud); /* baud rate */
settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; /* no parity */
settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; /* 1 stop bit */
settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
settings.c_cflag |= CS8 | CLOCAL; /* 8 bits */
settings.c_lflag = ICANON; /* canonical mode */
settings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; /* raw output */

tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &settings); /* apply the settings */
tcflush(fd, TCOFLUSH);

  if (fd == -1)
  {
   /* Could not open the port. */
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");
    //std::cout << "Echec de l'ouverture du port" << std::endl;
    res = system("printf \"Echec de l'ouverture du port \n \" > /dev/tty1"); //failed to open
  }
  else
  {
      res = system("printf \"Port serie OK \n \" > /dev/tty1"); //opening OK
  }
  while (fd!=-1) {


      //read the port
      do
                  {
                      tampon= read(fd,buffer,1);

                      if(buffer[0]=='\r')
                      {
                          read(fd,buffer,1);//read the following char which should be \n
                          break;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          data.append(1,buffer[0]);
                          printf ("data = %i \n",buffer[0]);
                      }
                  }while(tampon>0);
}

  close(fd);  /* cleanup */

return a.exec();
}
```

I know the while loop is kind of dirty like that by i don't understand why my printf are not here and why i seems to lose control of the application (can't ctrl+c it). It is my first time working on serial communication so maybe i missed something, it would not be surprising.

Comment: Qt has a [QSerialPort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) class you might be interested in, since it looks like you're using Qt.

Comment: @Steve I know but when trying to use it i have an error "unknow module", this is why i try to make the serial communication the "old" way.